# Water-tite valve broken

Tags: water, valve

On the new home I moved into. I found this behind the refrigerator.

several questions.

1. Can I replace the broken part? Which part should i buy?
2. It's connected to the refrigerator. But I'm going to buy new refrigerator and dont' have plan to use this water valve. What is best method to terminate this line? If I can't fix the broken valve lever and, therefore, can't close the water, can I replace the white hose with something that is closed-end? Is there such a part?

thanks!

[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

That valve is not broken.

The blue handle is there to be used when needed.

Normally that hose supplies water to the fridge ice dispenser and the valve is always open.

If you wish to remove the hose you can do that by closing the vale and unscrewing the hose.

If the valve handle is not working you can use a wrench or pliers to operate the valve.

Then you could screw on a cap.

Answer (score 2):

The blue handle should be screwed to the valve.

If you're lucky the screw just came loose and fell out and you can replace it with a new screw, though it will be hard to match because they are not standard.  If you're *really* lucky you'll find it on the floor.  Just screw it back on.

More likely, because the valve was mounted with the handle on the bottom, the screw collected dripping condensation, the head rusted off, and the stem of the screw remains in the valve.   In that case you should replace the whole have.  If you don't want to, and don't plan to use it you can use the knob to turn the valve off without the screw, just hold it on and turn it.